# How to do Autosuggestion in C# using elasticsearch (NEST)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using elastic search (NEST) in my API application.
Create Indexing for the search based on Name. Its working fine.

```
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var item = new NameIndex { ContentId = data.ContentId, 
name = data.Name };
client.Index(item);
```

Now I want to generate a new API for Auto-suggestion for the above index. The purpose of this API is for the user when he begins typing the name, and the first letter is B - loads all list of stations starting in B, then next letter "B" cuts the list down further to stations starting in BB etc.

How could I do this?

Comment: Take a look at the Completion Suggester - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below search query can fetch the data from the elastic index as per the user typing value (queryValue),It's working for auto suggestion

```
var data = client.Search<NameIndex >(i => i.Query(m => m
.MatchPhrasePrefix(c => c.OnField(p => p.name )
.Query(queryValue)))
).Documents.ToList();
```

Comment: Even I did something like this and from the resultant documents, I added requried fields to the list and then use this list as input to either AutoCompleteExtender or jquery autocomplete to display suggestions below the textbox. Is there any other way than this?

Comment: In this case, API returns the list of suggestions data, I think this can be accessed by AJAX call (API) and bound to UI

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev. Yeah even in my case it just generates results based on our mappings style. I'm looping through the results.documents and adding them to the list and then binding them to UI